# Pan and tilt bracket for a stepper motor

Tags: otherservos, stepper-motor, motion

Currently, I'm using a [pan tilt bracket](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10335) that works with the servos I have (spark fun product 9065), and are generic to all servos. However, servos aren't accurate enough. I'm looking at other options, but have limited knowledge about them. What would you recommend?

An important consideration is that I need my motor to tilt in two dimensions, to any random $x, y$ coordinate accurately. To do this, I think I'll need some sort of attachment to the motor shaft, like the pan tilt bracket.

What motor and bracket would you recommend I use to go to any random $(x,y)$ coordinate?

Comment: Hi Scott, and welcome to *robotics*.  Unfortunately *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* aren't something that a stack exchange site is good for. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and hopefully we can modify this question into something a bit more answerable.

Comment: I made the modifications, and asked for a more general answer.

Comment: Sorry *Scott* but I'm afraid that this is still essentially a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), since you appear to want a generic off the shelf solution which may not even exist (now or in the future) as there are so many different shapes and sizes of motor. Quite often in *robotics* we have to make brackets and mounts specific to our application, and specifying motors based on the performance required is a skill in itself. See questions like the rather ambitions one [here](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/869/37).